# d3 multiple lines with labels

Tags: d3.js, visualization

I am trying to make a time sequenced line chart in D3 with multiple line paths.  I want to apply text labels to these paths.

What I am currently doing is using a utility function to make several `d3.svg.line` elements based on properties of the data (the values of `plotProps`, which are keys from my json data).

```
function makeLine(prop){
         return d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d){ return x(d.date); })
            .y(function(d){ return y(d[prop]); });

    }

var plotProps = ['registered','subscribers','total','anonymous'];

 plotProps.forEach(function(prop){
        line = makeLine(prop);
        svg.append("path")
          .datum(graph_data)
          .attr("class", "line datapath")
          .attr("d", line)
          .attr('prop',prop)
          .style('text-anchor','middle');

      svg.append('svg:text')
        .attr('class','label')
        .attr("y", "")
        .attr("x", "")
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text('foobar');

    });
```

My approach here feels really counterintuitive to the data-join approach of d3, in that my line generation is not compatible should the data source be dynamic.  I can't seem to get the labels to appear properly, either.  Most of the examples use labels added to the g element - should I add them to the path for my case (just text above each line)?  Passing functions to the x,y attrs of the text elements I append outputs nothing in the console when the args are logged.

Is there a way to generate mutliple lines that will allow me to chain these label calls?  I hope I have been clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/). You might have to reformat your data slightly to do this, but then you should be able to pass in the array of arrays for the different lines and append each line accordingly. Text labels work in a similar fashion.

The reason why the text labels don't work for you is probably because you are not setting the `x` and `y` attributes (or rather not setting them to valid values).